# Oracle's database link allows user to query on multiple physical databases

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a solution or workaround in which MySQL will communicate with other Databases such as oracle, postgrey, MSSQL etc

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible in native MySQL.

I was read about it, but I didn't try an experimental FEDERATED_ODBC engine:

http://capttofu.livejournal.com/3152.html

The official [FEDERATED Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html)  only allow to connect to another MySQL database servers.